# Why do clones remove their helmets if stormtroopers don't?

Tags: star-wars

Reading [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138267/why-do-stormtroopers-wear-helmets) question, there are many good answers to why stormtroopers don't remove their helmets.

Despite all the reasons given, he clone troopers do.  Why ?

Comment: This will be entirely situation dependent...StormTroopers **do** remove their helmets..we just haven't seen it often if at all until now.

Comment: Storm troopers and clones are not the same thing. Can't expect them to behave the same.

Comment: I'll just see it from the other side, the maker's, not the spectator's: it's no big deal if clones take off their helmets when they're drawn animations that can be copied/pasted (with little differences though). It's another story when you shoot a movie with armies of storm troopers — clones to crown it all! It's much simpler to handle it when all of them leave their helmet on and only one (or a few) removes it, right? All you need is then find/leak a circumstantial reason... or let the public figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

whom do we actually see remove their helmets clone wise in canon?
Obivously, the clone CT-5555 "Fives" and some others do it in the clone wars season - but in the movies I can only recall unhelmet clones at two occasions:

(1) in the training facility on Kamino as childs or whilst eating at the cantina.

(2) CC-2224 during a meeting with Obi-Wan Kenobi, I assume this was for better understanding purposes. Obivously, given the fact CC-2224 was a clone commander MARSHALL, who had command of over 35.000 clones, it seems to be in his full authority to remove his helmet when he pleases to do so.

Clones where designed to follow any order without a doubt, but else had the freedom to finish their assignment by any means they saw fit that were within' their parameters. This set them apart from the droids in a good way as mentioned by Lama Su in EPII:

> LAMA SU:They're immensely superior to droids, 
>   capable of independent thought and action.
>
> OBI-WAN: Very impressive.
>
> LAMA SU: I'd hoped you would be pleased.

On the other hand, I found a reference as to why Stormtroopers wouldn't do so if not absolutely necessary from EPVII:

> CAPTAIN PHASMA: FN-2187. Submit your blaster for inspection.
>
> FN-2187: Yes, Captain.
>
> CAPTAIN PHASMA: And who gave you permission to remove that helmet?
>
> FN-2187: I'm sorry, Captain.
>
> CAPTAIN PHASMA: Report to my division at once.

Comment: The Clone Wars TV series is as canon as the films so making a distinction there is unnecessary and it is replete with un-helmeted clones

Comment: I wont join a discussion here, I'm just saying that I didn't make a difference, I just said that in the clone wars a few do it, nothing else. And thats due to the fact that clones can actually THINK and not just do what they are supposed to do if necessary. :)

Answer (score 4):

Part of the reason why the military and other organizations adopt uniforms is depersonalization. If everyone is wearing the same outfit, it creates a sense of interchangeability, that every person is a cog in the machine, ready to substitute if one of them should fall. If someone beside you is shot, you step into their place in the ranks instead of stopping to check on Bob, the guy who collects plastic unicorns as a hobby.

The clones were raised (and seemingly programmed) for obedience and a lack of self-identity, so there's no risk of individuality, but the stormtroopers are humanoid recruits, so the regulations likely require wearing of helmets at all times, ostensibly for the purpose of safety (compromise of environmental conditions, rogue Rebel sniper) but moreso because it keeps the stormtroopers thinking of each other as units, not as individuals.

Glancing over, it looks like [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/138286/23243) to the other question discusses the depersonalization in stormtroopers to a greater extent.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are obvious production differences. In the films (IV - VII) storm troopers are baddies, we want them dehumanized. Where as in the films II and most of III they are characters we are meant to relate to and empathize with. With the clone wars this is especially the case.

There is also the issue of individualism. Storm troopers are not clones (or at least not in known cannon). So there is an effort to make them more uniform. Clones are uniform with or without a helmet (baring hairstyle, and scars) so there is less impact in removing it.

Comment: «*Storm troopers are not clones*» Huh? Weren't they during the imperial era?

Comment: @nasha They were 'clone troopers', of the republic army. Quite weather the switch from them being clones, and to being known as 'imperial storm troopers' was synchronous is unknown.

Comment: Since the clone army was Palpatine's [secret] will while he was senator it didn't change during his reign so it would be logical that the storm troopers were then still clones, right?

Comment: We don't know when they stopped using clones, or why. But by the time of star wars rebels they are recruiting and training non clones to be storm troopers.

Comment: Ah, ok. Haven't watched the series. Not available where I live, alas.

Answer (score 0):

The Imperial armed forces the audience of the movies see is divided into Ranking Officers of the Imperial Navy, and Stormtroopers.

The Clone Army only has clones, some of which are high ranked, but still wear armour.

There is a pretty well established trope that sergeants, commanders and heroes do not wear helmets.

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HelmetsAreHardlyHeroic
http://www.dakkadakka.com/dakkaforum/posts/list/447814.page (Warhammer 40k)
https://www.reddit.com/r/HaloStory/comments/3ku63f/how_come_sergeant_in_the_unsc_marines_dont_wear/ (Halo)

So the answer is, none of the Stormtroopers we see in the movies are important enough in the plot, or high ranking enough to fit into the trope of not wearing helmets. There's no need for the audience to be able to tell them apart. There are plenty of ranking officers in the Imperial Navy that don't wear a helmet, they just don't wear body armour either.

Clones not wearing a helmet are those that meet the TV trope. The audience needs to recognise them.

Comment: Thats not true, stormtroopers are not part of the Imperial Navy. They're elite units, from my understanding they are not even part of the Imperial army but a separated branch.

Comment: @ devaron - I should have been more clear. I am providing an out of universe answer. Using information written in books decades after the movies were made is not relevant to the decisions made in the production of the movies.